# iLO Linux Installation stuck due to "Unable to find any valid media"

Tags: linux, redhat, ilo

Good Morning All,

I'am a dummy in this area and I am trying to install Linux Red Hat 8.3 on a remote machine with HP iLO 5; the features of the remote machine are the folowings:

Company:                HPE
Product Name:           ProLiant DL385 Gen10 Plus
UUID:                   32343150-3837-5A43-3231-303730325830
Server Serial Number:   CZ210702X0
Product ID:             P14278-B21

I have followed all the istructions requested to me by the iLO interface but once I arrived to the step of the guided installation when it checks all the media iLO give me the error: "Unable to find any valid media" as shown in the attached image:

[HP iLo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQvSh.gif)

I've tried to rexecute the whole procedure but it does not works, it could be a parcticular server configuration? Or maybe a parcticular configuration of iLO? Could you please help me?

I am available for any clarification

Best regards,

Stefano

Comment: I don't see any media there either. Exactly how did you attach it?

Comment: Hi,  i did not made any configuration about the media of the machine.   HP iLo error is the image link where I show the issue i faced

Comment: How did you intend to boot the server?

Comment: Hi, I intend to boot the server with iLO graphic user Interface and  of the .iso image file of the SO is requested as Image file CD/DVDROM; I've passed it rhel-8.3-x86_64-boot.iso

Comment: Hi, I met same issue. I add on virtual drive of remote console an image file CD/DVDROM which is an iso vmware and  I get same issue: "unable to find any valid media". So how ilo remote console takes into account of virtual drive?